# Private method JavaScript

Tags: javascript, class, oop, methods, private

I need a little help when I invoke a private method on my class using hash -> `#`, I get an error called "Invalid or unexpected token".
So I need to know how I can access private method or what is wrong in my code.

this my code:

```
class Poligono{
    
    constructor(altura, largura){
        this.altura = altura
        this.largura = largura
    }

    get area(){
        return this.#calcularArea()
    }


    #calcularArea() {
        return this.altura * this.largura
    }
}


let var_poligono = new Poligono(50, 60)

console.log(var_poligono)
```

and this is an error i get:

> c:\Users\Mix\Documents\testes\POO-JS\01-Encapsulamento.js:62
> return this.#calcularArea()
> ^
> SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Comment: I never heard of using a hash as a method prefix in JS

Comment: Seem like your browser/environment [doesn't support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields#browser_compatibility) private class methods/fields

Comment: @jrswgtr it's a fairly new feature of the language.

Comment: [Here's the JS environment compatibility list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields#browser_compatibility) (ie covers browsers and server-side envs like Node and Deno).

Answer (score 1):

The code produces no error when running in latest chrome so I guess it is a browser support issue. Check https://caniuse.com/?search=private%20methods

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, the error indicates a browser compatibility issue. [The compatibility list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields#browser_compatibility)  shows the minimum browser version requirement to use private method:

[image: version requirement]

Run the following snippet, and the result is displayed as `3000`.

```js
    class Poligono {

        constructor(altura, largura) {
            this.altura = altura
            this.largura = largura
        }

        get area() {
            return this.#calcularArea()
        }


        #calcularArea() {
            return this.altura * this.largura
        }
    }


    let var_poligono = new Poligono(50, 60)
    console.log(var_poligono.area)
```

You may see an error like below when you click on the `Run code snippet` button:

```
{
  "message": "SyntaxError: private fields are not currently supported",
  "filename": "https://s...content-available-to-author-only...s.net/js",
  "lineno": 20,
  "colno": 24
}
```

It indicates that your current browser version is not compatible with running private class features.